# Connecting to detached container in gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

### Cannot connect to detached container from Gitlab's CI

I start detached docker container being an HTTP server and try to connect to it from the pipeline script, but get connection error:

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 9000 after 129268 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Here is the complete `.gitlab-ci.yml` that reproduces the connection problem:

```yaml
stages:
  - Tests

with_server:
  image: docker:23.0.2
  services:
    - docker:23.0.2-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  stage: Tests
  before_script:
    - apk add --update --no-cache curl python3 && ln -sf $(which python3) /usr/bin/python
    - docker info
  script:
    - docker run --rm --detach --name that_server python:3.11-slim-bullseye python3 -m http.server 9000
    # that inspect is for extracting IP of that_server
    - curl $(docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' that_server):9000
  after_script:
    - docker rm -f that_server
```

`docker-dind` is being used in order to call docker commands in the CI pipeline according to the [gitlab's guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker). That is supposed to allow to build and run container and then connect to it.

#### Side-facts:

- The problem does not exist when I run it locally (`docker run` && `curl`).
- `docker build` works
- `docker run hello-world` works
- creating a network and connecting the container there does not help
- creating another container and connecting from it WORKS - e.g. with the following command:

```bash
docker run --rm --name that_client python:3.11-slim-bullseye python -c "from urllib import request; req=request.Request(\"http://$(docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' that_server):9000\");print(request.urlopen(req).read())"
```

The problem is when I try to connect from "host" which is `gitlab-runner` executor. I just don't know why and how to get a possibility to "connect" to the detached container.

The purpose of such arrangement is to start my application in a container and then execute tests against it. Do you know what do I miss here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `docker:dind` service, which starts the container. Your application should be accessible under `docker:9000` instead of the container IP.

**Update:**

I noticed you have not mapped the port, you also need to add `-p 9000:9000` to your `docker run` command. Also add a slight timeout before the curl, `sleep 30` for example, as it takes some time until the container starts in dind.

Comment: Oh yes! I tried publishing and the `docker` name, but it seems that I missed the `sleep 30`, that's why I got `curl: (7) Failed to connect to docker port 9000 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server`. Using all of that together makes it working. Thanks!